# How to encode the excel sheet data before passing to api

Tags: jquery

In my project, I am uploading an excel sheet and its data is getting passed to backend api in params.In return backend is sending the response, and same excel sheet i am printing in UI.

But if excel sheet has some tags like `<script>alert("hello")</script>` or `<b> / <i>` tags in any of the columns, then in UI it is displaying the alert, or printing the letters in bold/italic... but i want it to work the same as in excel sheet, means instead of performing this script behavior, they should be printed as it is in UI too.

I thought of using encodeURIComponent function in the data before sending it to api, but that is giving me the error in api

> > "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> >     JSONObject["fileInfoJson"] is not a JSONArray."

fileInfoJson is the param name.

Anyone please guide me what is the issue and what i should do.

```
var jsonData = {};
jsonData.userName = localStorage.username;
jsonData.fileInfoJson = encodeURIComponent(jsonInfo);
```

Comment: Only way that comes to mind would be for each cell to have a `textarea` or `text input` set to `readonly` and styled to be invisable that would hold each value.

Comment: that is not feasible as table contents as well as no. of table rows and columns, all are dynamic

Comment: Ideally any HTTP API should send data in encoded format only..so i am thinking best solution will be to encode excel data before sending it to api.